# Why don't I need to use the dereference operator with a map's .at() method?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, dictionary, reference

In C++, I've always learned to use the address-of and dereference operators like so:

```
char s = 's';
char *t = &s;

t = 't'; // would be a compile error, because t must first be dereferenced
*t = 't'; // this works
```

Then why does this work?

```
map<string, vector<char>> letters = {
    {"first", {'a', 'b', 'c'}},
    {"middle", {'l', 'm', 'n'}},
    {"last", {'x', 'y', 'z'}}
};
vector<char> section = letters.at("first");
```

It's my understanding that `.at()` returns a reference to the mapped element at the specified key. Why can't that last line be this:

```
vector<char> *section = letters.at("first"); // this doesn't work!
```

I can then go on to use `section`, accessing its methods with the `.` operator instead of the `->` operator, even though, according to [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/at/) it returns a reference:

```
char first_letter = section.at(0); // not section->at(0);
```

What's going on here? Am I actually getting a reference to the `vector` inside the `map`? If so, why don't I need to use the arrow operator to dereference the returned element variable so that its method can be invoked?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between pointers and references?

Comment: My understanding is that a pointer is a variable that has a reference as its value, and it must be dereferenced before it can be used to modify the value of the original variable.

Comment: Wow, this has been sobering.

Comment: I don't understand why someone downvoted this question.  The OP has put in some effort and is genuinely trying to understand the use of pointers.

Comment: btw: warning: character constant too long for its type: 'first', ...

Comment: This question is ignoring all compiler errors/warnings (no vote)

Answer (score 4):

In C++ a reference is, in short, an alias for an object, and is different from a pointer.

By dereferencing a pointer you're accessing the pointed-to object (or reference).

With a reference you use the `.` operator to access members, with a pointer you use the `->` operator.

`map<string, vector<char>>::at()` returns a `vector<char> &` (a reference, which in practice looks to the programmer as an actual object, i.e. as if it was a `vector<char>`). That's not a `vector<char> *` (a pointer to `vector<char>` object).

Comment: There are explicitly no pointers or references to references in the language. And it does not *quite* look like an object: Keep the difference in mind for lifetime- and modification-tracking. Anyway the best of th three explanations so far.

Answer (score 3):

You're confused about references and pointers. The common use of the word 'dereference' doesn't help things for you either, as you don't actually have to dereference references.  ;-(

You can think of a reference as being like a pointer, but with added syntactic sugar that hides it's underlying representation.

So if you have a reference like `int &iref = i;` you can use `iref` just like you'd use `i`.

```
  iref = 42;
  iref += 100;
```

But, if you have a pointer, you must use the dereference operator `*`.

```
  *iref = 42;
  *iref += 100;
```

Comment: I suspect using multiplication (i.e. `*`) as an example here is just confusing matters even more ;) Perhaps consider using `+` instead?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Indeed. But at least I put a space before the `*=`. Changed now...

Comment: Yes indeed, that helped ;)

Answer (score 2):

`at()` returns a reference, not a pointer:

```
vector<char> &section = letters.at("first");
char first_letter = section.at(0);
```

You cannot assign a reference to a pointer, but you can use the `&` address operator on a reference to get a pointer to the item being referenced:

```
vector<char> *section = &(letters.at("first"));
char first_letter = section->at(0);
```